# How to password protect Laravel site within apache vhost?

Tags: laravel, apache, vhosts

I am trying to password protected my Laravel application with Apache vhost file. It asks for my username and password but it keeps asking this for every route and every time I reload the page.

Can somebody please explain me how do I need to change the config file in order for the site to ask password and username only once?

This is the directory part of my vhost file:

```
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
    ServerName staging.app.mysite.ee
    ServerAlias www.staging.app.mysite.ee
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/app/staging/public

    <Directory "/var/www/mysite/app/staging">
            Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

            #AuthType Basic
            #AuthName "Restricted Area"
            #AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
            #Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put below code in either .htaccess file in document root of your project. Or you can add below code in apache configuration file.

```
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile FULL_PATH_OF_FILE_HTPASSWD
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd file should contain username and password.

```
Username:HASHED_PASSWORD
```

This will prompt password only once ie. will be set in session.

Comment: Still prompts after each request